# Confusion between $f(x)>f(0)$ or $f(x)<f(0)$ for a differentiable function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function. Which of the following is necessarily true?

1. If $f'(0)>0$, then $f(x)>f(0),\forall x\in(0,1)$.
2. If $f'(0)<0$, then $f(x)<f(0),\forall x\in(0,\delta)$ for some $\delta>0.$

Firstly I tried to use a counter to claim any of these false. For 2. if $f(x)=e^{-x}$, differentiable and $f'(x)=-e^{-x}$ and $f'(0)=-1<0$, but here $f(x)<f(0),\forall x\in(0,\delta)$, $\forall \delta>0$ (not for some $\delta>0$).

One more confusion I have, since in 2. $f'(0)<0$ then the function f will be decreasing in a very small neighbourhood of "$0$" and for that neighbourhood it will behave as a local extremum (maximum here) that is what option 2 is all about, similarly for the existence local minimum as in option 1 we can talk about a small neighbourhood of $0$. On the basis of it, 2 will be correct.

Using differentiability particularly at $x=0 $ (as the question hints), we have that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=f'(0)$ and $f'(0)>0$ $\implies f(x)>f(0)$ (this need not happen for all $x$). How do  I draw a conclusion formally or any counter example ?

Thanks.

Comment: For a counterexample to the first claim, try for a differentiable function such that $f(0) = 0$, $f(0.5) = 1$ and $f(1) = -1$.